# Selenium Java API why driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getText() always returns empty

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, title, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Selenium2` with `Java API Version 2.53.1` and `chrome driver Version 2.24` to print out several values.

But for the tag: `<title>test</title>`
the function
`driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getText();` always returns empty.

My question is, how to get API functions working again?

BTW: `Selenium3` is beta and broken for `chromedriver` and `geckodriver`, too!

On the other hand the functions:-

`driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getTagName();` and `driver.getTitle();`
returns the right values.

I tried to work around the issue with JavaScript code to no avail:

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        a_tag_name_title = (ArrayList<RemoteWebElement>) js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('title');");


        System.out.println("Is empty? " + a_tag_name_title.isEmpty());
        for (RemoteWebElement object: a_tag_name_title){
            System.out.println("Title tag: " + object.getText());
        }
        found = false;

        for (RemoteWebElement object: a_tag_name_title){

            found = object.getText().contains("title");
        }
        assertTrue("Title tag not found", found); //sanitiy check if "getElementsByTagName" is working, too

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [`WebElement#getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) returns the visible `innerText` of the element on the Page, while `innerText` inside `<title>` tag is not visible on the page that's why you'r getting empty text.

To determine before using [`WebElement#getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) that element is visible or not use :-

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).isDisplayed();
```

If you are using above statement, you can see it's always returns `false`.

To work around of this, you can use `WebElement#getAttribute("textContent")` or `WebElement#getAttribute("innerText")` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getAttribute("textContent")

driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getAttribute("innerText")
```

Comment: It seems like it would be a lot easier to use `driver.getTitle();`.

Comment: @JeffC you're right, OP is already using it an it works fine, but he is curious to know about why `driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getText();` returns empty?? Thanks to point it out